# Java имплементация Интерфейса

Tags: java, android

При имплементации одного и того же интерфейса во многие классы приложения, этот интерфейс пересоздается каждую имплементацию, то есть все значения в нем заново инициализируются и выделяется память под них, или же инициализация интерфеса происходит один раз за жизненный цикл приложения, и в каком моменте ?

Comment: о каких значениях в интерфейсе вы говорите?

Comment: О любых. Примитивы, массивы примитивов, массивы классов, enum.
Подумав понял что массивы точно не пересоздаются, так как значение занесенное в такой массив из одного класса можно получить в другом классе имплементировав интерфейс с этим массивом в оба класса.
Передаются ссылки.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman  
  
Тогда в какой момент реализуется интерфейс и можно ли его реализовать повторно в нужный момент ?  
То есть в интерфейсе есть массив классов, массив примитивов[N].  
Они заменяются по ходу программы. Как то вызвать интерфейс на реализацию что бы все обнулилось.

Comment: уточните о каком интерфейсе идет речь? о графическом интерфейсе? или о интерфейсе который описывается ключевым словом inteface? или о чем-то совсем другом?

Comment: смИшьно... навреное вы не читали шапку.

Answer (score 2):

Интерфейс не создается вообще, это грубо говоря соглашение, которое должен выполнить класс, реализующий его. И уже класс содержит поля методы и конструкторы.

Comment: Вызывать в каждом классе приложения андроид один и тот же интерфейс (в нем различные данные) нормальная практика или могут быть осложнения ?

Comment: Вы не вызываете один и тот же интерфейс, вы вызываете различные методы у классов - наследников интерфейса. А наследников у интерфейса может быть несколько.

Comment: В каждом классе я делаю (implement MyInterface, AnotherInterface)  
Я что то не понял суть вышенаписаного .

Comment: написав class MyClass implement MyInterface, вы обязуетесь реализовать методы, описанные в интерфейсе. И в дальнейшем, вы можете вызывать методы у класса через интерфейс: MyInterface mi = new MyClass();          mi.method();

Comment: Я интерфейс использую для хранения и быстрого доступа к данным.  
    /**
     * DATA_INT[0]      -   distance
     * DATA_INT[1]       -   sprites on screen
     */
    int[] DATA_INT = new int[2];

    /**
     * DATA_BOOL[0] - debug
     * DATA_BOOL[1] - выход с платформы
     */
    boolean[] DATA_BOOL = new boolean[3];  
Что бы не таскать данные из класса в класс передавая в нужные методы других классов. Методы в интерфейсе отстутствуют.  
Нормальная ли практика использовать интерфейс как хранилище ?
Простите за жесть с форматированием.

Comment: @vito-Z80 Использовать интерфейс, как хранилище данных, абсолютно не нормальная практика.

Comment: это я так понимаю по конвенции не нормально.  
А если необходимо? Даже если просто надо, если откинуть конвенцию кода.

Comment: Интерфейс может только обеспечивать доступ к объекту - реализации этого интерфейса. т.е. быть ссылкой на объект класса, грубо говоря.